# Coredata multithreading violation when using ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, core-data, objectmapper

```
required public init?(map: Map) {

            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).privateContext
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Shop", in: context)
            super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
            self.mapping(map: map)


    }
```

So basically It's throwing an exception on the third line

```
super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:
    0x1028df220 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x1028df221 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
->  0x1028df224 <+4>: ud2    
    0x1028df226 <+6>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I thought that if I used a privateContext it might solve the problem, but that wasn't true.

```
lazy var privateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateMOC.parent =  self.managedObjectContext
        return privateMOC
    }()
```

I can't do something like context.performBlock inside an initMethod

By the way I'm using tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper and this is the Shop class managedobject. It conforms to the Mappable protocol.

```
public class Shop: NSManagedObject, Mappable
```

I thought everything was working fine because I could see the objects in SQLiteViewer but random crashes started happening so I added this -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 and was surprised that It threw an exception this early.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling `Map()` on the main thread, and then assigning `entity` to a private threat context, then attempting to do work on it in the Main thread. If you want to use that private thread context, you'll need to call a `perform` block that'll do it on a private thread:

```
context.performAndWait {
  super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
  do {
    try context.save()
  }catch{
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: It helped me to prevent an ugly crash.